# In my c++ code of Bubble sort i have problem with my output when i give input in ascending order

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

It works fine when I give input in Descending order like `4321` but fails when I change the order even by one position like `1432`

```
for(int pass = 1; pass <= n-1; pass++)
{   
    for(int j = 0; j < n-pass; j++)
    {
         if( a[j] > a[j+1])
            temp = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;                    
    }   
}
```

---

OUTPUT

```
Enter the size of the array
4

Enter the elements of the array
1
4
3
2

Elements of the array are :
1432
Elements of the sorted array are :
0001
```

Comment: you are missing brackets

Comment: Now is a good time to learn: _always_ use brackets. Even for one-line blocks.

Comment: @OP C++ is not Python.

Comment: thank you so much for your help im a beginner and i will learn

Comment: You are violating the basic structure of if statement, as it requires brackets if we have to execute more than one statements inside the if statement!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing brackets .

By default, next line to **if** is considered to be in scope
if you don't add brackets after **if**.

It has contributed to some  great bugs
[Apple Bug](https://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/)

```
for(int pass = 1; pass <= n-1; pass++)
{   
    for(int j = 0; j < n-pass; j++)
    {
         if( a[j] > a[j+1]) { // here
            temp = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;     }       //here        
    }   
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to Learn Debugging your code, Find a good IDE   it will help you

Answer (score -2):

Put a bracket for if condition like:

```
    if( a[j] > a[j+1]){
            temp = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;  
    }
```